# How to detect touch on SKShapeNode in Video Sphere?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I use this simple code for playing 360 video. I need to add a point to the video - there is no problem with that. But how to track clicks on it? In this example, adding a point occurs in the viewDidLoad method.
I tried touchesBegan, but this method does not work. I really hope for your help

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    var sphereNode: SCNNode!

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

    func createSphereNode(material: AnyObject?) -> SCNNode {
        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 100.0)
        sphere.segmentCount = 96
        sphere.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = true
        sphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = material
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0)
        return sphereNode
    }

    func configureScene(node sphereNode: SCNNode) {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }


    func startCameraTracking() {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { [weak self] (data, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
            self?.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(attitude.roll + Double.pi/2.0), -Float(attitude.yaw), -Float(attitude.pitch))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "google-help-vr", ofType: "mp4")!)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: url )
        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
        let size = CGSize(width: 1025, height: 512)
        videoNode.size = size
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        let spriteScene = SKScene(size: size)
        spriteScene.addChild(videoNode)

        // How to detect when tapped?
        let circ = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50), cornerRadius: 25)
        circ.fillColor = .red
        circ.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        videoNode.addChild(circ)

        sphereNode = createSphereNode(material:spriteScene)

        configureScene(node: sphereNode)
        guard motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable else {
            return
        }
        startCameraTracking()
        player.play()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        sceneView.play(self)
    }
}
```

I did a self class for the object SKShapeNode, in order to track clicks through the touchesBegan method. But all without success

Comment: You have SKShapeNode isUseractionEnabled set to true.  That means the SKShapeNode class will receive touches, which does you no good because you didnt override it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UITapGesture recognizer to get the 2D point then use [SCNSceneRenderer .hitTest(_:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer) to get all of the possible intersections along that ray.  Note that the method is on the SCNSceneRenderer protocol, which SCNView conforms to so you may have missed it in the SCNView documentation.

```
    @IBAction func tap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        if let firstResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil).first,
            //Do stuff with firstResult here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to get a click in SCNNode, but how to convert this click in SKNode?

Comment: The HitTestResults give you the localcoordinates, in terms of geometry.  If your node is just a plane then it should be easy to scale the local coordinates to coordinates in your texture (ie the video): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult

Comment: Actually I see you have a sphere; fortunately you can use the same link to get the texture coordinates of the intersection with `func textureCoordinates(withMappingChannel: Int) -> CGPoint`.